# Round And Show To 2 Decimal Places?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a small question to ask. How to round a numeric field upto 2 decimal places, and also show it with 2 decimal places only

For example the following would return 255.88000000000

```
select round(255.87908765444,2)
```

How to get 255.88 only?

Answer (score 19):

All you need is:

```
CAST(255.87908765444 as decimal(18,2)).
```

When you convert data types in which the target data type has fewer decimal places than the source data type, the value is rounded.
From [microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(CAST_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true)

Answer (score 1):

If you need it as a string, this should work:

```
select format(round(255.87908765444,2), 'N2');
```

Answer (score 1):

> use string function substring & char index

```
select SUBSTRING(convert(varchar(20),round(255.87908765444,2)),
                 1,
                 CHARINDEX('.',convert(varchar(20),255.87908765444))+2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select round(convert(decimal(18,2),255.87908765444),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes We can use the above solution is..

```
ROUND(CAST(psd.Price AS DECIMAL(20,4)), 2)
```